# Is there an online wallet that supports 2FA and pays inflation?

Tags: xlm

I'm currently holding my XLM on an exchange wallet (Binance) and I don't believe they will pay inflation as I do not own the private key of an exchange wallet.
I don't want to maintain my own hardware wallet.

Which cloud wallets will offer strong security 2FA and will allow me to get inflation payouts?

Answer (score 9):

I'd suggest using a paper wallet. It's very easy to do with Stellar and you have to put your private key in on stellar.org anyway to receive inflation. There is also 2FA available in password keeper programs. Here's a quick walk through:

- Go to https://www.stellar.org/
- Click "Wallets" on the top right of the page.
- Click the link where it says "Go to our Account Viewer to access our lightweight client."
- Click "Generate". This will give you two keys, a public one that starts with a 'G' and a secrete one that starts with an 'S'.
- Now you can either print these out or store them in a secure location. KeePass is a open source program that offers 2FA. Just use a key file stored on a USB and a password for your two forms.
- Once this is all set sign into the account viewer page where you generated your keys.
- Send your lumens to this address and set you wallet to receive inflation. You can send a test transaction to make sure everything is set up correctly. Hooray for low transaction fees!

To receive inflation you need a critical amount in your wallet. So unless you got fat stacks (as pantheon52 pointed out about 52,000,000 lumens) in that wallet there is a free pool run by reddit users [here](https://lumenaut.net/). There are easy to follow directions on their website and a reddit thread is available [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Stellar/comments/7qsgmp/community_pool_is_live/).

Comment: "To receive inflation you need a critical amount in your wallet". Roughly '52,000,000' lumens* (103,629,819,513)*.0005 = 51814909.7565 

[Source](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/inflation.html)  
[Dashboard](https://dashboard.stellar.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Generate your own account and send the money to that address, it is that simple. Head over to https://www.stellar.org/account-viewer/ and click on "Generate key pair for a new account" then save that info (both public and secret key) print it or store it on a pendrive or old laptop unplugged from the internet. That's all you need to have your own account managed by yourself. Then send all the money from any exchange to that account (send 1 XLM first to activate the account and verify you didn't make a mistake).

And never ever share your secret key with anybody or any website.